# Is this an appropriate use for decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.df = pd.read_table(name)
```

and a bunch of methods like this:

```
def valid_cond1(self):
    # check if cond1 is satisfied with respect to self.df and return
    # a DataFrame of rows not satisfying cond1   

def valid_cond2(self):
    # same deal
```

etc.  In the end, I want to take the output of each of these methods, and return to the client a formatted list of the bad rows.  I can do this for `valid_cond1` by adjusting the implementation like so:

```
def valid_cond1(self):
    # err_df = rows of self.df not meeting cond1
    bad_lines = []
    for ix, val in err_df.iterrows():
        bad_lines.append("Error in line %s: %s.  Cond1 not met.." % (ix,val))
    return bad_lines
```

But I don't want to write the same logic for each of these functions (perhaps there are very many of them).

Is this a place where I could use a decorator? Or is there another way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: So how accessible is `err_df` outside of each method? A decorator can access globals, `self`, the arguments going in, and the return value, no problem. So if you *returned* `err_df` then sure, no problem, a decorator can do that  for you. Otherwise, just use a function.

Comment: Write a method that takes another method as input, calls it, and formats the result as you desire.

Comment: Is there any chance you would want the output from these functions for other reasons? You could write a separate formatting function for this and pass the results to it. Separate program logic from presentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, a different `err_df` is returned by each of these methods.  So a decorator should be able to work in theory?  I've been having trouble implementing one, because the `valid_condn` methods take a variable number of arguments (perhaps I should've made that clear in the question).  Is it still possible?  Not that it's preferable to the answer below, I just wanted to see how it's done.

Comment: @tdelaney That's probably the best way to approach the problem.  Just wanted to see the decorator approach, if it was possible.

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd: variable number of arguments are not an issue for decorators, just use `*args, **kwargs` and pass those on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't jump to decorators for something like this, but perhaps a more generic method

```
def check_condition(self, condition):
    # check the condition
    return bad_lines  # etc.

def valid_cond1(self):
    # define condition_1
    return self.check_condition(condition_1)

def valid_cond2(self):
    return self.check_condition(condition_2)
```

If you can't make the conditions into something simply passable, you could do something like this to avoid repeating the error printing code at least:

```
@staticmethod
def invalid_condition(err_df):
    # bad lines stuff here

def valid_cond1(self):
    # calculate err_df
    if err_df:
        return self.invalid_condition(err_df)
```

EDIT: Just for fun, a decorator version. I've been known to (ab)use decorators, so I can understand the desire:

```
from functools import wraps

def print_error_info(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        err_df = func(*args, **kwargs)
        bad_lines = []
        for ix, val in err_df.iterrows():
            bad_lines.append("Error in line %s: %s.  Cond1 not met.." % (ix,val))
        return bad_lines
    return wrapped

# use
class MyClass:
    # *snip*

    @print_error_info
    def valid_cond1(self):
        # whatever you need
        return err_df
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is probably the way to do it, but I just wanted to see how it could be done with a decorator.

Comment: Although the answer to your question is probably simply "no," see my edit for an (untested) implementation of a decorator for this use case. The problem with using a decorator in my mind here isn't really related to the functionality but more to the readability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I came up with roughly your `print_error_info`, but it does not seem to do anything.  Decorating `def id(df): return df` with `@print_error_info` returns `df` instead of `["Error in line 0: ...", ...]`.

Comment: In any case, I think I will take your advice and not try to use decorators.

Comment: You'll want to check exactly what you're returning from `def wrapped: ... return bad_lines` make sure that's not just `df`!

Comment: I copy/pasted your function just to ensure that it wasn't something like that, and same result.

Comment: Found the bug! It has to be `@wraps(func)`.